# TabbarController child controller always return nil - Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to access the objects from child controller but it always returns nil. Please check the below code.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let vc: UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
vc.selectedIndex = 2
let vc1 = vc.viewControllers?[2] as? FormViewController //this line returns nil
vc1?.fillUserData(dataDic: convertJsonStringToDictionary(jsonString: decodedURL))
vc1?.formViewDelegate = self
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please shed some light.

Comment: It's probably nil because the 3rd view controller isn't a `FormViewController`. Maybe it's a navigation controller.

Comment: Am sure third view Controller is formviewcontroller and it's embed in navigation controller.

Comment: That's my whole point. `vc.viewControllers?[2]` is *not* a `FormViewController`, it's a `UINavigationController`. That is why you get `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, the 3rd tab is actually a `UINavigationController` which has the `FormViewController` as its `rootViewController`.

Update your code as:

```
if let nc = vc.viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController, let vc1 = nc.topViewController as? FormViewController {
    vc1.fillUserData(dataDic: convertJsonStringToDictionary(jsonString: decodedURL))
    vc1.formViewDelegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let nav = vc.viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController
let vc1 = nav?.topViewController as? FormViewController
```

note : you should not access any UI element here

```
vc1?.fillUserData(dataDic: convertJsonStringToDictionary(jsonString: decodedURL))
```

as it would crash the app